# ¿Porque una petición de ajax me devuelve el error de CORS pero una petición desde android funciona?

Tags: android, ajax, webservice, swift, .asmx

Actualmente estoy trabajando en la creación de un mapa que muestra las ubicaciones de las sucursales. Para ello el departamento de sistemas de la empresa nos ha otorgado el acceso a un *webservice asmx*, que nos devuelve esta información, esta consulta se implementó exitosamente en las apps de android y de ios, es una petición a la que no se le envían parámetros (no se si sea relevante pero el asmx tampoco tiene seguridad no está montado con https).

```
http://urlprovedor.mx/ws/direcciones.asmx/getCarburaciones
```

El problema es que al intentar hacer la misma petición desde ajax devuelve el error

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://urlprovedor.mx/ws/direcciones.asmx/getCarburaciones%20?_=1561393493766 (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://urlprovedor.mx/ws/direcciones.asmx/getCarburaciones",
      cache: false
    ).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Por supuesto he leído un poco del tema aquí en StackOverflow, algunos usuarios recomiendan instalar un plugin al navegador pero esta opción es inviable para nosotros, otra opción es modificar el ws para añadir urls o ips desde los que se permitirán las peticiones, pero como menciono nosotros no tenemos forma de modificar el código del lado del servidor.

Nótese que efectivamente la petición se pretende hacer desde otro dominio, dado que nuestro cliente tiene 2 sitios (uno para sus clientes y otro para sus proveedores) y el ws es montado solo en el sitio de sus proveedores.

¿existe alguna forma de hacer la petición como se logra hacer el android e ios teniendo en cuenta nuestras limitantes? ¿por que en el caso de las apps no aplica dicha revisión de cors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por desgracia no pude resolver mi problema, debido a que `jsonp` es la única manera de evitar el error de `CORS`, pero al usar `jsonp` se forza que las peticiones sean por `GET` y el servidor que me lista las sucursales solo responde las peticiones `POST`. Entonces, encontre 2 alternativas para lidiar con esto.

1. usar la clase `SoapClient()` de php en el backend de mi página para obtener el listado del webservice y luego imprimir variables de javascript con el resultado:

   $client = new SoapClient("miurl");
        $response = $client->__soapCall("getCarburaciones", array($cuerpoPeticion));
        $estatus = $response->getCarburacionesResult->Result;
        if ($estatus == 1) {
           $strResultados = $response->getCarburacionesResult->Data;
           echo "var strResultados = '" . $strResultados ."';";
        }

con esto pude usar la variable `strResultados` en javascript una vez que la página ha sido cargada.

2. Solicitar al equipo de desarrollo del ws que añada las cabeceras necesarias para conectarme con ajax desde otro dominio.

Comment: Si vas a hacer eso, me parece mas facil que uses CURL en el backend, incluso si la lista de sucursales es mas bien estatica podes cachear los resultados para no ir menos veces al otro servidor.

Comment: ¿Porqué consideras que  `CURL` sería una mejor opción para consultar un `WS SOAP` que la misma clase especifica para eso?, en tu  segunda observación tienes razón dado que la información de las sucursales se modifica muy pocas veces al año.

Comment: Mala mía. Me perdí la parte de que se trataba de un servicio Soap. Pensé que era un GET y devolvía un json. En ese caso tenés razón en usar el soap client.

Answer (score 1):

Eso sucede por que estás enviando la petición desde un sitio diferente al que estás actualmente.

Por ejemplo si te encuentras en google.com y quieres enviar la petición hacia urlprovedor.mx recibirás el mensaje que mencionas.

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

Agregar las opciones crossDomain & cambiar dataType a jsonp

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://urlprovedor.mx/ws/direcciones.asmx/getCarburaciones",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

Comment: ¿En este ejemplo que sería `setHeader`?

Comment: beforeSend
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings )
A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, aunque por desgracia no pude lograr el objetivo, ya que al usar jsonp forzosamente la petición se hace por GET y el ws retorna el html en lugar de ejecutar el método. Pero aún así tu respuesta me ayudó a entender el problema, hacer pruebas y demostrar que esto es responsabilidad de los administradores del servidor.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás haciendo la llamada con `ajax` usando un script descargado de un dominio pero que se dispara hacia otro dominio (de ahí el cross origin).

La solución está en manos del servidor al que le estas enviando el request de ajax (El que tiene que devolver las sucursales).

Ellos tienen que devolverte una cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`: y el dominio de donde se descargó el script que ejecuta el ajax. Lo podes ver en el request enviado bajo la cabecera `Origin`.

Alternativamente, y considerando que se trata de un `GET`, y bajo el supuesto que:

a. no se necesite enviar cookies ni cabecera de autorización, y
b. no haya impacto en que de otro sitio (un tercero) también pudiera hacer un ajax para recuperar esos datos.

Entonces, el servidor podria devolver  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, que habilita a cualquier dominio hacer la misma consulta que vos estás haciendo, por detrás, utilizando ajax.

También a tener en cuenta. Dependiendo que cabeceras estés incluyendo en tu `GET`, tal vez sea necesario que el servidor, además de autorizar el origen, autorice esas cabeceras.

Una última nota: este problema no lo tendrías si el script con el ajax lo pudieras bajar del mismo servidor que te provee la lista de sucursales.

> ¿existe alguna forma de hacer la petición como se logra hacer el
>   android e ios teniendo en cuenta nuestras limitantes? ¿por que en el
>   caso de las apps no aplica dicha revisión de cors?

Es diferente porque, por ejemplo Android (que es el que conozco), utiliza un cliente http tal como si ingresaras la url en la barra de dirección del navegador. No se utiliza ajax (XHR).